# Why is integer variable showing a warning sign in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, variable-initialization

In the below picture, why is `totalNotes` variable shown with a warning sign in Eclipse ? If it is because I have initialised `totalNotes` only inside for loop, then by that logic shouldn't `costOfSweet` variable also be marked with a warning sign ?

Code : 
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

```
public class BUYING2 {
    static int sum,noOfSweets;
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int totalTestCases,costOfSweet,totalNotes;
    int noteDenominations[];
    String firstLineString,secondLineString;
    String secondLineArray[];

    totalTestCases=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    for(int i=0;i<totalTestCases;i++){
        firstLineString=input.readLine();
        secondLineString=input.readLine();
        totalNotes=Integer.parseInt(firstLineString.split(" ")[0]);
        costOfSweet=Integer.parseInt(firstLineString.split(" ")[1]);
        secondLineArray=secondLineString.split(" ");
        noteDenominations=new int[secondLineArray.length];

        for(int k=0;k<secondLineArray.length;k++){
            noteDenominations[k]=Integer.parseInt(secondLineArray[k]);
        }
        System.out.println(getNumberOfSweets(costOfSweet,noteDenominations));
    }
}

public static int getNumberOfSweets(int costOfSweet,int noteDenominations[]) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sum=IntStream.of(noteDenominations).sum();
    noOfSweets=sum/costOfSweet;
    int temp;
    for(int j=0;j<noteDenominations.length;j++){
        temp=noteDenominations[j];
        noteDenominations[j]=0;
        if(IntStream.of(noteDenominations).sum()/costOfSweet>=noOfSweets){
            return -1;
        }
        noteDenominations[j]=temp;
    }
    return noOfSweets;
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you mouse over it, it will tell you. In this case, it is because the variable is assigned, but *never used*.

Comment: Please always post code as code-formatted text, not as an image. We can't copy and paste your code into our IDE, and we can't test your code.

Comment: Sorry. Have updated the code now. The picture was to show that it throws a warning sign